# Avro "not open" exception when writing generic records using Apache Beam

Tags: avro, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am using `AvroIO.<MyCustomType>writeCustomTypeToGenericRecords()` for writing generic records to GCS inside a streaming data flow job. For the first few minutes all seems to be working fine, however, after around 10 minutes, the job starts throwing the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: not open
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:183)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:133)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:200)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:136)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: not open
        org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:34)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:275)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:237)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.processElement(StreamingSideInputDoFnRunner.java:72)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:181)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:102)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.lambda$onTrigger$1(ReduceFnRunner.java:1057)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnContextFactory$OnTriggerContextImpl.output(ReduceFnContextFactory.java:438)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.SystemReduceFn.onTrigger(SystemReduceFn.java:125)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(ReduceFnRunner.java:1060)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.ReduceFnRunner.onTimers(ReduceFnRunner.java:768)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:95)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.processElement(StreamingGroupAlsoByWindowViaWindowSetFn.java:42)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:115)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:73)
        org.apache.beam.runners.core.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:80)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:133)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:43)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:48)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:200)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:158)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:75)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:1227)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$1000(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:136)
        com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$6.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:966)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: not open
        org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.assertOpen(DataFileWriter.java:82)
        org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:299)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.AvroSink$AvroWriter.write(AvroSink.java:123)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles.writeOrClose(WriteFiles.java:550)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles.access$1000(WriteFiles.java:112)
        org.apache.beam.sdk.io.WriteFiles$WriteShardsIntoTempFilesFn.processElement(WriteFiles.java:718)
```

The data flow job continues to run fine though. Just to give some background about the streaming job: it pulls messages from Pub/Sub, creates a fixed window of 5 minutes with a trigger of 10,000 messages ( whichever comes first), processes the messages and finally writes to a GCP bucket whereby each specific type of message goes to a specific folder based on the type of the message using `.to(new AvroEventDynamicDestinations(avroBaseDir, schemaView))`.

**UPDATE 1:** Looking at the timestamp of this error, it seems to be coming up exactly with an interval of 10 seconds, so 6 per minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had exactly same exception. My problem came from wrong schema, null schema to be exact (not found by schema registry)

Comment: Sorry, should have updated my post earlier. The issue was null schema being passed to create generic record function, same issue as pointed out by @jonathan-herbatka